# how to know to which port my mobile phone is connected (in the /dev filesystem)

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems

I wonder how to know to which port my mobile phone is connected (in the /dev filesystem) when I plug it (I am using a Raspbian OS) ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `dmesg -T` directly after plugging it in. Ensure the phone can establish a data connection over USB - you may need to enable debug mode in Settings. Compare /dev filelisting before and after to see all device files for your phone. `find /dev 1>/tmp/list1`, plug it in, wait 10 seconds, `find /dev 1>/tmp/list2`, then `diff /tmp/list{1,2}` .

If in doubt whether the phone even registers on the Pi, issue `lsusb -v`. Pi1+2 will not be able to supply enough current for charging, and that may foil your worthy endeavour.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

After to have enable debug mode in Settings on my mobile phone, nothing appear about my mobile in the /dev filesystem, so after having searched during lot of time I find this article on WIKI Debian : 

https://wiki.debian.org/Huawei/E220

The following commands permit me from viewing my mobile device in the /dev filesystem :

lsusb
.....
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1003